# Azure service bus or just Azure web app when using SignalR

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, signalr, chat

I never used the Azure. Now, i with a problem.
I am going to do a Chat on Xamarin Forms using SignalR. So, the chat will have a 1:1 and a group 1:all . Its for a small group of 700 to 1.000 persons. Looking at the internet, i didnt understand if i have to pay for Azure App Service (standard) + Azure Bus Service, or just Azure Bus Service, or just Azure App Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you only need to pay for Azure App Service to create a single Web App if you want to use SignalR.

The only reason you'll need Service Bus is if you decide to scale your Web App to multiple instances. To synchronize across multiple web apps, SignalR requires a messaging backplane. That's what Service Bus would be used for. Your other options for a SignalR messaging backplane are Redis (very fast), or Azure SQL (slower). I personally use Service Bus for my SignalR messaging backplane. But again, you do NOT need Service Bus if you're only using one instance for your web app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean with instance ? I am a begginer... In my case, i will have a Android and iOS app (xamarin)... chats 1:1 and one group with all 800 users. Nowadays are almost 800 users....maximum of just 1k.

Comment: ``What do you mean with instance ?`` it is VM instances that run your app. And as Rob Reagan said, if your web app will be scaled to multiple instances, you could refer to [scaleout in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr).

Comment: @FredHan-MSFT, I am assuming that MC Fer is looking to have a SignalR Hub on the server that receives all chat messages and forwards them to the appropriate recipients. Given that, I think that a Web App would be a better choice than a standalone app hosted on a VM. Your thoughts?

Comment: @MCFer, you can create an Azure Web App and will by default have a single instance. If you need more processing power than you can get from a single instance, you can add additional instances. Two instances would be like having two servers running the same code, with an Azure Network Load Balancer routing incoming requests to one of the two instances. You only need a Service Bus backplane if you go above more than one instance. You can read more on multiple instances by searching for "Scale Out" as opposed to "Scale Up".

Comment: @FredHan-MSFT I think Rob Reagan got my question ! " I am assuming that MC Fer is looking to have a SignalR Hub on the server that receives all chat messages and forwards them to the appropriate recipients. " Is this !! I am just affraid of if will be enough... i know that i can scale out after, but the problem is that i have to give a price for the client...

Comment: @RobReagan As a example... if i want to host a Web Api and one MVC (signalR), i need 2 instances on Azure ?

Comment: No, you can host both the WebAPI and MVC pages in the same web application on the same Azure Web App instance.

Comment: @RobReagan Jesus !! lol... Applied to my case, what do you think will be necessary ? 800 to 1k users ... 1 group with all and chats 1:1 ... i will use SignalR to transmit the messages... they also need to transmit images sometimes... i am thinking about a Web Api and SQL to this... everything on Azure... So, a Azure App Service Plan Basic 1 with 1 instance plus a Azure SQL seems to be enough ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139404/discussion-between-rob-reagan-and-mc-fer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an MSDN account you get a certain amount of free credits to put towards it, but each type of Azure Service generally has a charge. Check out the pricing pages on azure and you'll be able to gauge which is your best option, alternatively if you aren't ties to Microsoft, then you can look at the RabbitMQ offerings of Amazon.

If you're unsure on the pricing, speak to a Microsoft Sales person, they've helped me out in the past and are quite good.

Comment: I'd also like to add that Azure has free app service plans `F1`. It has restrictions like no custom urls, no websockets (so your SignalR connection will default to Long Polling), and no always-on. But if performance isn't your concern, that could work.

Comment: Yes. But my question is about use service bus or not. I asked to Microsoft and waiting the answer. What i understood is that how my app is for a small group, i don´t need the service bus, but i am not sure. Like i told, i will have just one group with all users (1 topic with maximum 1k subscriptions) or chat 1:1